# Disable portb a/d on pic18f25j50

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I want PORTB as digital inputs and it seems RB0 to RB3 are not responding to digital inputs..

So how can I disable analog on these port pins?

I'm using mikroc pro for pic..

I had the same problem with pic18f2550 but it had portb a/d enable bit in project settings...

But pic18f25j50 doesn't have this option available anywhere ... His can it be done?

Comment: How is this not directly and clearly answered in the datasheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registers you are looking for are ANCON0 and ANCON1. If they are set to zero they are analog and if they are set to one the pins are digital. They control the digital/analog configuration of pins. You can find a description of these registers in the data sheet under section 21.0 10-BIT ANALOG-TO-DIGITAL
CONVERTER (A/D) MODULE